# 401 Unauthorized error using twitter API

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, parse-platform

I always get a `401 Unauthorized` response for this twitter API request.  This is confusing because I have a twitter session and am signing the request. Thanks in advance.

```
    NSURL *retweetAPIURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/%@.json", tweetID]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:retweetAPIURL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

if (self.twitterSession) {

    [self.twitterSession signRequest:request];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        block(nil, responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        block(error, nil);
    }];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
} else {
    block([self createErrorWithMessage:NSLocalizedString(NSLocalizedString(@"TWITTER LOGIN ERROR", nil), nil)], nil);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the request is being signed? Why don't you just use `SLRequest`?

```
NSURL *retweetAPIURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/%@.json", tweetID]];
ACAccount *account = // ...;
SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:retweetAPIURL parameters:nil];
request.account = account;

NSURLRequest *preparedURLRequest = [request preparedURLRequest];

// create your AFHTTPRequestOperation using preparedURLRequest
```

Comment: I will try this solution next But the problem is I used Parse.com for backend and Login Twitter in the app (not login on settings). so, would you telling me how to check the request is signed or not ?